# A two color bar plot in R

Tags: r, rna-seq, ggplot2

I have raw read counts of miRNAs in two conditions like below

```
> head(long1)
             miRNA Read count Condition
1:  hsa-miR-539-3p         33    living
2: hsa-miR-199b-5p        102    living
3: hsa-miR-146a-3p         27    living
4:   hsa-let-7a-3p        186    living
5:    hsa-miR-1275         54    living
6:  hsa-miR-29a-3p       6464    living
>
```

For each individual miRNAs, I want to show the difference of raw read counts across conditions by

```
p=ggplot(data = long1, aes(x=long1$miRNA, y=long1$`Read count`)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Condition))
p <- p + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Condition"))
p <- p + xlab("miRNAs") + ylab("Raw mapped reads") + ggtitle("s vs living with cancer")
p + facet_wrap( ~ miRNA, scales="free")+theme_bw() add_pval(p, pairs = list(c("s", "living")), test='wilcox.test')
```

Which returns this

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This plot is not good

How I can a plot like below in which miRNAs are on Y axis and two colours shows the conditions like this

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using Google well is one of the best skillsets you can possibly learn in programming-allied fields. The style of plot you're looking for is a "grouped bar plot". I googled "r grouped bar plot" and found a nice link: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2.html

The key is to use `position=dodge` alongside `color=Condition, x="Read count", y=miRNA` )not sure ow you'd quote the name `"Read count"`, might be better off renaming that column to `readcount`).